# Can`t integrate Google Maps into Tab component

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zk

I am working with ZK framework. I know that ZK already has Google Maps component, but I use CE edition, so this component isn`t available for me. I tried to integrate it with the help of javascript:

```
gmaps.zul
<zk>
    <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #map_canvas {
       height: 100%;
    }

    @media print {
      html, body {
         height: auto;
      }

      #map_canvas {
         height: 650px;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <html> <![CDATA[
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=uk">
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
       var myOptions = {
           zoom: 8,
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
  myOptions);
    }

    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&' + 'callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>
    <div id="map_canvas">
    </div> 
     ]]></html> TEST TEXT
</zk>
```

as for me it works fine and I can see Google Maps. But actually I would like to integrate it into a Tab element of another page:

```
<?page id="main-page"?>
   <zk>
   <window id="wnd" title="Tabs of Content" width="100%" height="100%" border="normal"> 
          <tabbox id="tbox" width="100%">
                <attribute name="onSelect">{
                    Window w = Path.getComponent("//main-page/wnd");
                    if (self.selectedIndex==1) {
                       Include inc = (Include)Path.getComponent("//main-page/wnd/project_tab"+self.selectedIndex);
                       inc.setSrc("gmaps.zul");
                     }
               }</attribute>
                <tabs>
                     <tab id = "tab1label" label="Tab 0"/>
                     <tab id = "tab2label" label="Tab 1"/>
                </tabs>
                <tabpanels>
                     <tabpanel>Test</tabpanel>
                     <tabpanel><include id="project_tab1" src=""/></tabpanel>
                </tabpanels>
             </tabbox>
       </window>
   </zk>
```

When I open this page and try Tab1, there is no Google Maps. 
How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try zk gmaps 3.0.0.Beta,
it can be downloaded at [zkgmapsz downloads list](http://code.google.com/p/zkgmapsz/downloads/list)

Regards,

ben

Answer (score 0):

You can create static html or jsp page with Google map code, and then you can load that page in iframe.

It's best option if you use CE edition.

You can create even custom ZK google map control with that "iframe map", with all functions that you need for map manipulation, but that will require some javascript coding.

That's what I have done.